# Can we apply cardinal/ordinal arithmetic to Lagrange's theorem with infinite group?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, set-theory

I was thinking about Lagrange's theorem theorems and the expression $\mathbb{Z}^2/\mathbb{Z}^1\cong \mathbb{Z}$, here superscript meant outer product and $/$ meant quotient.  It occurred to me that though the order of $\mathbb{Z}$ was infinite, $\omega_0$, buy since the power law held for ordinal/cardinal, this was equivalently to say that $\omega_0^{2}\omega_0^{-1}=\omega_0^1$.

Thus can we apply cardinal/ordinal arithmetic to Lagrange's theorem with infinite group?

Comment: There are no negative powers of ordinals.

Comment: @MattSamuel No division either, but it works.

Comment: Infinite groups are not *ordered* (without additional structure), so it doesn't make sense to talk about ordinals in this context; only cardinals, where what you have is just $\aleph_0*\aleph_0=\aleph_0$. In any case, the theorem does hold for infinite cardinals; five seconds with Google took me to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangesGroupTheorem.html.

Comment: Cardinal arithmetic works if you write it in the product form, $$\operatorname{card} G = \operatorname{card} H\cdot \operatorname{card} G/H\,.$$

Comment: Incidentally, if you're interested in a context where negative powers of ordinals and more general ordinal operations can be made sense of, I recommend looking into the _surreal numbers_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of whether cardinalities are finite: a subgroup $H$ of $G$ satisfies $|G|=[G:H]|H|$, and $[G:H]$ is a cardinal. So there always exists a cardinality $\kappa$ with $|G|=\kappa|H|$, and when all cardinalities are non-negative integers we say $|H|$ divides $|G|$. However, we can't infer $[G:H]$ as $|G|/|H|$ if $|G|,\,|H|$ are the same transfinite cardinality, say $\lambda$. The axiom of choice then implies any cardinality $\theta\le\lambda$ satisfies $\lambda=\theta\lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a group $G$ and a subgroup $H$, no matter what you have $G = \coprod_{c\in G/H} c$.

Now (using the axiom of choice in case $G/H$ is infinite) we may find for each $c\in G/H$ a representative $a_c \in G$, such that $a_cH =c$, so that $G= \coprod_{c\in G/H} a_cH$ and in particular $|G| = \sum_{c\in G/H} |a_cH| = \sum_{c\in G/H} |H| = |G/H||H|$. As you can see, this does not depend on any finiteness assumption : this holds no matter what size $G,H,G/H$ are.

Of course, with infinite cardinalities you cannot divide : $|G|/|H|$ makes no sense if $|H|$ is infinite; but you can still multiply and so (a version of) Lagrange's theorem still holds.